# Find the probability of U.

Tags: probability

If $U$ and $V$ are two independent events with $P(U)<P(V)$, the probability that both $U$ and $V$ occur is $6/25$, and $P(U|V)+P(V|U)=1$. I want to find $P(U)$.

$U$ and $V$ are independent so;

$P(U|V) = P(U)$

$P(V|U) = P(V)$

$P(U) + P(V) = 1$

$P(U ∩ V)  = P(U)P(V)  = 6/25$

How can I find $P(U)$?

Comment: $P(U)+P(V)=1$; $P(U)\cdot P(V)=\frac{6}{25}$, so you have two equations and two variables.

Comment: Put $x=P(U)$, $y=P(V)$ if that makes it easier to think about.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you @RiverX15

Comment: Thank you @Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both $U$ and $V$ are independent, then
$$P(U\cap V)=\frac{6}{25}$$
$$P(U)\cdot P(V)=\frac{6}{25}$$
$$P(U)\cdot (1-P(U))=\frac{6}{25}$$
Solving for $P(U)$, we end up with two solutions
$$P_1(U)=\frac25\ \text{and}\ P_2(U)=\frac35$$
Since $P(U)\lt P(V)$, we have
$$P(U)=\min\left\{\frac25, \frac35\right\}=\frac25$$